# how to connect postgresql to aws RDS using Django

Tags: python, django, postgresql, amazon-web-services, docker

I am unable to connect my postgreSQL database to AWS RDS while using Django.

I am not sure what i am doing wrong but i have the configuration below:

```
Django
docker-compose
postgres
```

[image]

#DJANGO Settings

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': "dbtest",
        'USER': "mastername",
        'PASSWORD': "somepassword",
        'HOST': 'dbtest.zmrHnee2mhLunL.us-east-2.rds.amazonaws.com',
        'PORT': 5432
    }
}
```

## docker-compose

```
version: "3.7"

services:
  backend:
    build: ./backend
    container_name: backend
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
    restart: "on-failure"
    env_file:
      .env
    volumes:
      - ./backend:/backend
      - ./backend/static:/backend/static
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    depends_on:
      - db
    links:
      - db:db
    networks:
      - db_network

  db:
    image: postgres:11.5-alpine
    container_name: db
    restart: always
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=dbtest
      - POSTGRES_USER=mastername
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=somepassword
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    networks:
      - db_network

networks:
  db_network:
    driver: bridge

volumes:
  postgres_data:
```

after starting the container `docker-compose up -d --build`

Now when i check `docker-compose logs`

I see the traceback below:

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 127, in connect
backend     |     conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
backend     | django.db.utils.OperationalError: could not translate host name "dbtest.zmrHnee2mhLunL.us-east-2.rds.amazonaws.com" to address: Name or service not known
```

and after creating another db instance and allowing it to be publicly accessible

```
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 127, in connect
backend     |     conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
backend     | django.db.utils.OperationalError: FATAL:  database "dbtest" does not exist
```

## security group

[image]

I have been trying to debug for hours, any help would be really helpful

Comment: Is your RDS instance inside of a VPC?

Comment: @jordanm yes, it is, linked to subnets etc as well... maybe its because it was no publicly accessible, so i created another db instance publicly available now I see the error above that i have updated on the page